# Auditd logging related to SELinux?

Tags: linux, audit, selinux

Is there any relation between auditd and SELinux? Or can we use auditd even if SELinux is disabled?

Comment: See https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-c84fad68bffc5eca190fa3a1aab3cac2cfe94a63

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELinux uses auditd for logging purposes, but auditd is independent from it. You can use auditd without SELinux present.

Comment: This is correct, but perhaps you could expand on how it works (e.g. how SELinux uses the _audit subsystem_, which auditd interfaces with).